# Exclude current day from collection filtered by current week (date product attributes)

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, product-collection

I have a product collection from Monday to Sunday (using attributes `date_from` and `date_to`). I want to show products from current week but I need to exculde the current date products.

I have

```
->addFieldToFilter('date_from',array('gteq',$thisweekmonday))
->addFieldToFilter('date_to',array('lteq',$nextsunday));
```

In this collection I want to exclude the current day, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can combine multiple conditions in `addFieldToFilter()` which will combined with `OR`.

Additionally, I'd suggest you to use the date comparison operators instead of `gteq` and `lteq`.

For the `date_from` attribute, the following will filter all products that have `date_from` between monday and yesterday OR between tomorrow and sunday (if that's what you want):

```
->addFieldToFilter(array(
    ['attribute' => 'date_from', 'condition' => array(
        'date' => true, 'from' => 'this week monday 0:00', 'to' => 'yesterday 23:59')],
    ['attribute' => 'date_from', 'condition' => array(
        'date' => true, 'from' => 'tomorrow 0:00', 'to' => 'this week sunday 23:59')]);
```

"this week monday 0:00" will be parsed with `strtotime()`, so it is a valid value. The times 0:00 and 23:59 are necessary because there is a bug in `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::_prepareSqlDateCondition` that treats `date` equal to `datetime`

If you want to learn more about the conditions that you can use in `addAttributeToFilter()` and `addFieldToFilter()`, take a look at `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::prepareSqlCondition()` - the core code is often the best documentation source.

I also explained `addFieldToFilter` in a bit more detail here: [addFilter vs addFieldToFilter](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96930/addfilter-vs-addfieldtofilter/97503#97503)

Answer (score 0):

I did not get a proper solution,

So, I suggest to divide the collection into two collections:

**Step1:**  1st collection from "this week Monday" date to yesterday

**Step2:**  and other collection from tomorrow to "next week Sunday"

**Step3:** union two collection using `union()`

### Example:

```
$collection1=Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');

$collection1->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array(
    'from' => $thisweekmonday,
    'to' => $yesterday,
    'date' => true, 
    ));
    
$collection2=Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');  
$collection2->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array(
    'from' => $tomorrow,
    'date' => true, 
    )); 


      
$collection1Select = $collection1->getSelect();
$collection2Select= $collection2->getSelect();

$mergedCollection = $collection1Select->union(array($collection2Select));
```

Your final collection is `$mergedCollection`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'gteq' use 'gt'. It would exclude the current date for your if the period your are trying to fetch the collection for is in the future.

Comment: gt will work if today is monday what if today is tuesday.then gt last monday will give current date also