# convert sql query to magento addFieldToFilter combine OR and AND

Tags: magento2.3, collection, sql

You can convert me this sql I did not arrive at combined OR and AND at the same time

SELECT * FROM `sales_order` AS `main_table`,
`sales_order_payment` AS `sop`
WHERE ((`status` = 'processing') Or
((`status` = 'pending') and (sop.method = 'chekmo') ))
AND (`updated_at` >= '2020-06-19 18:24:59')

Please, can someone help or suggest anything?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot nest `AND` condition in `OR` with the addFieldToFilter. So you could use Zend_Db_Select::where method to write custom nested queries.

```
    $collection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()
        ->addFieldToSelect('*');

    /* join with payment table */
    $collection->getSelect()
        ->join(
            ["sop" => "sales_order_payment"],
            'main_table.entity_id = sop.parent_id',
            array('method')
        );


    $collection->getSelect()->where(
        "status = 'processing' OR (status = 'pending' AND sop.method = 'checkmo')"
    );

    $collection->addFieldToFilter('updated_at' , ['gteq' => '2019-06-19 18:24:59']);
    return $collection;
```

For more information about addFieldToFilter refer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/139760/77673

Thanks